# How do I use Ajax to Post only 1 value of an array at a time sequentially and wait for the response before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax Jquery Script that is supposed to post an array of dates to a php page get a result, and if it is the correct result it displays a success message in a div on the page, if it is not the correct returned result, it displays an error. What is supposed to happen is that each date should be sent 1 at a time, wait for the response before moving to the next one. The script seemed to have been working fine, but I noticed the dates were being returned in random order. After investigation I learned this was because The Ajax call was sending multiple request at the same time. I guess that is why it is called Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (Lol). Anyway, I have been at this for hours and can not seem to find or comprehend the way to resolve this. I have read some stuff about Javascript promises and all kinds of things but I don't get it. If someone could help out with some code help it would be super appreciated!

Here is the entire HTML file with the Javascript and Ajax Call included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dates Range</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $(function(){ startProcess({"7":"2016-01-07","8":"2016-01-08","9":"2016-01-09","10":"2016-01-10","11":"2016-01-11","12":"2016-01-12","13":"2016-01-13","14":"2016-01-14","15":"2016-01-15","16":"2016-01-16","17":"2016-01-17","18":"2016-01-18","19":"2016-01-19","20":"2016-01-20","21":"2016-01-21","22":"2016-01-22","23":"2016-01-23","24":"2016-01-24","25":"2016-01-25","26":"2016-01-26","27":"2016-01-27","28":"2016-01-28","29":"2016-01-29","30":"2016-01-30","31":"2016-01-31","32":"2016-02-01","33":"2016-02-02","34":"2016-02-03","35":"2016-02-04","36":"2016-02-05"});
        // Ajax to send Date
        function startProcess(arg)
        {
            $.each(arg, function(index, val) 
            {
                $.post('returnsample.php', { query : val }, function(resp) 
                {
                    // resp = $.parseJSON(resp);
                    if (resp == "YES IT WORKED") 
                    {
                        $('.append-range').append('<strong>Date : </strong>'+val+'<p>Got Right Answer</p><br>');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.append-range').append('<strong>Date : </strong>'+val+'<p>Got error</p><br>');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    })
</script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Range between two dates:</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
                <div class="row">
            <div class="append-range"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe don't use each to cycle through the array, but rather increment through it with an incrementing value that only increments when you get the result you want.

Comment: Why are you not sending the full array, processing each date, and then sending back an array of results? Seems like a much more sound UX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chxm9xvx/1/) to demonstrate the desired effect. I've changed your object to an array, though, because it was number indexed.

What the script does, is make an ajax call, and when `success` has been triggered, it will decide what to do, and restart, looping over the whole array.

```
u = 0;
function startProcess(arg){
  if(typeof arg[u] !== 'undefined'){
    $.ajax({
      url: "returnsample.php",
      method: 'post',
      query: arg[u],
      success: function(resp){
        if(resp == "YES IT WORKED"){
          $('.append-range').append('<strong>Date : </strong>'+arg[u]+'<p>Got Right Answer</p>')
        }else{
          $('.append-range').append('<strong>Date : </strong>'+arg[u]+'<p>Got error</p>')
        }
        u++;
        startProcess(arg);
      }
    })
  }
}

startProcess(["2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-09","2016-01-10","2016-01-11","2016-01-12","2016-01-13","2016-01-14","2016-01-15","2016-01-16","2016-01-17","2016-01-18","2016-01-19","2016-01-20","2016-01-21","2016-01-22","2016-01-23","2016-01-24","2016-01-25","2016-01-26","2016-01-27","2016-01-28","2016-01-29","2016-01-30","2016-01-31","2016-02-01","2016-02-02","2016-02-03","2016-02-04","2016-02-05"]);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast help @Vincent. This was exactly what I needed. The fiddle helped me see it. I super appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an idea.

1.separate your async (ajax) as a callback function

2.pop each items from array

3.use promise pattern for async function. jquery provides promise API using [jQuery.defered here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to do this is a callback chain. I whipped up an example in straight javascript that should give you an idea. Comments throughout to help explain.

```
// first, don't use an associative array unless you really need it,
// a regular array will be much easier to iterate
var arg = [ "2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-09","2016-01-10","2016-01-11","2016-01-12","2016-01-13","2016-01-14","2016-01-15","2016-01-16","2016-01-17","2016-01-18","2016-01-19","2016-01-20","2016-01-21","2016-01-22","2016-01-23","2016-01-24","2016-01-25","2016-01-26","2016-01-27","2016-01-28","2016-01-29","2016-01-30","2016-01-31","2016-02-01","2016-02-02","2016-02-03","2016-02-04","2016-02-05" ];

// start off at index 0
next(arg, 0);

function next(arr, index) {

    // set our terminating condition
    if (index >= arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    // we will set up the next iteration by binding our arguments ahead of time
    var nextCallback = next.bind(null, arr, index + 1);
    // call out to your service, with the current value and a function to process the next once completed
    callService(arr[index], nextCallback);
}

function callService(value, next) {
    // call your service here, I am simulating with setTimeout
    // the key here is that we don't call next() until AFTER we have processed our item
    // $.post(.... function (response) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // simulate a response since timeout won't provide us one
        var response = value;

        // do stuff with your response
        console.log(response);

        // when done, call the next one
        next();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I ended up trying the solution by @Vincent first. His fiddle made it easy to see and it was most similar to my original code, but I tested your solution and it worked as well. I will put it in my arsenal! Thanks for the time bro!